# Under what circumstances are flights moved earlier by one hour or several?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, flight-status

Not that long ago, I was talking with an airline passenger who was complaining about a major US airline carrier having "a habit of" moving flights *earlier* (that is, the opposite of a delay) to the point where he (and his party) were missing flights, including one connecting flight that had been moved up so early that it boarded while he was still on the incoming flight which was according to its original schedule.  I think he was talking about all flights within the US.

Subsequently, I showed up at a US airport 4.5 hours early for a flight figuring that would be **plenty** of time, but after arrival found that the flight had also been moved earlier by more than four hours, and the gate had changed from one end of the airport to the opposite end (as far apart as two gates could be with an indoor connection).  So sorry!  Also, it's the last flight of the day on that route.

Under what conditions do airlines do this?  It sure would be helpful to be able to better predict such occurrences in the future, or at least understand the causes.

Edit: This question was flagged as a duplicate of [that one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53687/are-airlines-allowed-to-move-up-the-time-of-a-flight), which focuses on airlines moving up flights by five or ten minutes.  The present question focuses on airlines moving up flights by e.g. an hour or few.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are airlines allowed to move up the time of a flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53687/are-airlines-allowed-to-move-up-the-time-of-a-flight)

Comment: I do have those details and even photos of the departures screen, but am not sharing it here because of the release of too much personal information.

Comment: If you won't share them your point is moot... I don't believe any airline actually moved up their scheduled flight by that long.

Comment: When was the flight moved? Airlines sometimes do change flight schedules, but they will do so weeks or months in advance, especially for a change of several hours. And when they do so, they generally contact you (or your travel agent) and work with you to deal with any connections that no longer work as a result of the schedule change. And the new time will be on your online itinerary and boarding passes. They don't just move up a flight by hours just right then and there.

Comment: It was moved the day of the flight, and as of less than 24 hours earlier the flight was still going out as scheduled.  If you don't believe this question, move on to the next one as you clearly don't know enough about this practice to have an answer.  It's not worth me revealing all that personal information just to be able to convince a few strangers on the Internet of something that they don't know about and can't shed any insight or understanding on.

Comment: What is "all that personal information" about a flight number?!

Comment: Flights are moved forward regularly for lots of different reasons, EasyJet being cited as one of the more egregious. It's likely you'll need to wait for a while until you get an informed answer.

Comment: If this really happened to you, and the change was made the same day, you would be due a refund at least.

Comment: If you don't want to give a flight number, date airline and departure airport might help.

Comment: @DJClayworth That (or really any one of those) combined with information in the question would likely be sufficient to uniquely identify the flight and route, and combined with what I've posted elsewhere significantly raise the amount of personally identifiable information.

Comment: This just doesn't happen barring some extreme, extreme circumstances.  The only way to know is to ask when it happens.  Impending weather could push the airline to operate a flight earlier just to move the aircraft.  Passengers that make it are lucky.

Answer (score 8):

Airlines reschedule flights on a regular basis, moving them forward, backward, cancelling them all together.  These changes are usually done several days, weeks or months in advance.  But sadly MANY travelers never bother to recheck their itineraries, and thus get caught unaware by the changes. And most check in counter agents assume the traveler is paying attention, so don't point out schedule changes at check in time.

Airlines can reschedule flights on the day of travel due to a specific issue on that date (such as an incoming hurricane, severe winter storm, etc).  When they make these last minute changes, they try to contact passengers via email sms or phone numbers.  But if you are traveling or if you left your home number on the booking but are at work, these notifications don't get through in a timely manner.

The date the OP mentioned where there were multiple flights moved up, likely had a weather related issue at the departure airport or an upstream airport.  The grumbling passenger was probably just that a grumbler, trying to get sympathy by exaggerating his situation.

Comment: @pnuts  Yes, but they try to get as many passengers notified and on that plane as they can, less folks to re-route later.  Travelers tend to view the plane for their flight only, but most aircraft have multiple flights (as do the crews) each day and not having the plane in position can have a cascading effect.

Comment: We have no idea where the planes were going in the situation mentioned.  There could have been an upstream issue that they wanted to get planes in & out of the next airport.  I had a flight moved forward by four hours for that exact reason, a typhoon heading towards the next airport and they wanted to get planes in and out of the airport well ahead of the storm's anticipated landfall.

Comment: Check in counters in my experience are pretty good about telling you of changes, and if you checked in 30 mins before departure as the OP claimed he did they would definitely say something.

Comment: @DJClayworth - my comment about check in counters was aimed at changes made well in advance and the silly tourists that don't bother checking their itineraries in advance to see if things have changed.  Obviously last minute changes would be relayed at check in time.

Comment: I agree. Just putting a different take.

Comment: Good answer, thanks!  Weather wasn't enough to explain the situation I observed with at least five different flights being moved up an hour or more, as there was no incoming storm predicted for the origin or the wide spread of destinations; weather was generally OK for flying nationwide with rain in some places as expected.  This implies other good answers still exist out there and can be added below.  @DJClayworth Not sure why you came up with that 30 minute figure, but I checked in nearly 24 hours in advance and the flight was still scheduled to go out on its original schedule then.

Comment: You said you arrived at the airport 4.5 hours early, and the flight left 4 hours early, so logically you arrived at the airport 30 minutes before it took off.

Comment: @DJClayworth Ah, I see.  I didn't go to the check-in counter at that time however; I had no bags to check and already had my boarding pass.

Comment: @WBT - Yes weather is not the only explanation, but is the most common one.  However several flights being scheduled to depart much earlier at the last minute IS indicative of an issue somewhere in the system. Airlines do not move flights forward by four hours at the last minute for the fun of it (irregardless of what grumpy claimed)